# Link without edit balloon in ckeditor5

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ckeditor5, ckeditor5-react

I used CKEditor5 with Reactjs,
I want to add the link without editing, I actually want to see the creation balloon once and it is at the time of creation
Then on clicking the link, without the 'editi balloon', to be directed to a specific target.
is that possible or I have to handle it with css and js code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I was able to find a solution, I hope it is useful for someone else
I added contenteditable:'false' in attributes of the Link and my problem has solved
When the link is not editable, it is displayed without balloons

```
 <CKEditor
            disabled={!this.state.isOrganizer}
              editor={ClassicEditor}
              data={this.state.Message}
              config={{
                toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'blockQuote', 'link', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList', 'imageUpload', 'insertTable',
                  'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'mediaEmbed', '|', 'undo', 'redo'],
                language: 'de',
                link: {
                  decorators: {
                      addTargetToExternalLinks: {
                          mode: 'automatic',
                          callback: url => /^(https?:)?\/\//.test( url ),
                          attributes: {
                              target: '_blank',
                              rel: 'noopener noreferrer',
                              contenteditable:'false' //<=========== solution***
                          }
                      }
                  }
                }
              }}
              onChange={(event, editor) => {
                const data = editor.getData();
                this.setState({
                  Message: data
                }, () => {
                   
                })
              }}
            />
```